# How to provide metadata for even links which are password protected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, metadata, meta-tags

I've a path, say /profile/history. If user is not logged in this path redirects to /login.

But when a person shares the url /profile/history I want social metadata to be related to history page i.e. view your history.

Instead what I get is metadata for /login page.

So is there a way to tell if request if from user or app, if user than redirect, or else provide empty meta page.

Unless there is a better way?

Comment: simply you can manipulate URL, when user share the URL you can add some path params to identify whether URL shared one or not.

Comment: how can i modify url if user types the path?

Comment: `/profile/history` contains who's history? History from the logged in user? Then If user A shares `/profile/history` you want to show metadata of user A... And if user B shares `/profile/history` you want to show metadata of user B?

Comment: meta tags on html generally dont contain information about invididual user but just describe page, and when links are shared those tags are used by twitter, facebook, etc to show what the website author wanted. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/markup

Comment: You didn't answer my question :P. If the answer is NO... then... can you clarify your question?

Comment: I no where implied that metadata is related to an individual user? if there is confusion it's an misassumption on reader's part :P